# NextJS (React) - Error: Invalid hook call (useState)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using NextJS for server side rendering & I am trying to use useState hook inside a component which is throwing :

> Error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

> My code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const Banner = ({ movies }) => {
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState(movies);

    return (
        <header>
            <h1> Banner </h1>
        </header>
    )
}

export default Banner;
```

> Directory Tree

```
/components/Banner.js
/pages
```

Getting same error when i use useEffect() like :

> *import React, {useEffect} from 'react'*

Comment: `import React, { useState } from 'react';`

Comment: Doesn't work, I tried that too.

Comment: This looks fine, error must be elsewhere, share rest of the code.